# Using React with Next.js demo is not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My Package.js

```
{
  "name": "nextjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "prod_start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^9.0.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  }
}
```

Below is the error log.

```
Error: Could not find a valid build in the 'xxx/nextjs/.next' directory! Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the server.
    at Server.readBuildId (xxx/node_modules/next-server/dist/server/next-server.js:425:23)
    at new Server (xxx/node_modules/next-server/dist/server/next-server.js:43:29)
    at module.exports (xxx/node_modules/next-server/index.js:4:10)
    at module.exports.options (xxx/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:2:161)
    at start (xxx/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:1:385)
    at nextStart (xxx/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-start.js:22:125)
    at commands.(anonymous function).then.exec (xxx/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:29:346)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
```

While running npm start it is display error inside node_modules/next-server/dist/server/next-server.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `npm run build` first. When you run `npm run start`, it's trying to *start* a local server so you can run your app locally. But if you just installed it and haven't yet built your app (as the error indicates), your local server doesn't have anything to serve up.

If you want to run it locally *while* you're developing (ie, with live reloading), use `npm run dev`.